# The values in a const list literal must be constants

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a `FocusNode` to list of texts but I fault to do so.

The userNameNode is:

```
 final FocusNode userNameNode =FocusNode();
```

The usage of userNameNode which caused the error:

```
Stack(
     fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: const [
        _Image(),
        _ListOfInputs(
          userNameNode:  userNameNode,
)]);
```

The error of userNameNode is:

```
The values in a const list literal must be constants.
Try removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.dart(non_constant_list_element)
The element type 'dynamic' can't be assigned to the list type 'Widget'.
```

The _ListOfInputs  class is:

```
class _ListOfInputs extends StatelessWidget {
      final FocusNode userNameNode;
      const ListOfInputs(
        this.userNameNode,
      );
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

your code is:

```
Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: const [
                _ListOfInputs(userNameNode:  userNameNode,)]);
```

so change it:

```
Stack(
      fit: StackFit.passthrough,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
      children: [
               _ListOfInputs(userNameNode:  userNameNode,)]);
```

because the list is not const.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the const keyword before the Stack.children and provide datatype for the `_Image` and `_ListOfInputs` methods to Widget instead of dynamic.

```
Stack(
  fit: StackFit.passthrough,
  textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
  children: [
    _Image(),
    _ListOfInputs(userNameNode:  userNameNode),
]);
```